# Expandable list´s adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am doing an Expandable list adapter to have my elements in one row and I have an ClassCastException but I don´t know why, here is my adapter´s code. I am novice doing adapters with android so any help is great, thank you so much.

```
 public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ChildModel childText = (ChildModel) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        TextView txtListChilddos = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView txtListChildtres = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView txtListChildcuatro = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView txtListChildcinco = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView4);


        txtListChild.setText(childText.getDate());
        txtListChilddos.setText(childText.getSong());
        txtListChildtres.setText(childText.getDuration());
        txtListChildcuatro.setText(childText.getArtist());


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

the exception is in this line:

```
 final ChildModel childText = (ChildModel) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
```

Comment: Im not sure but I think that method is returning a String object and not a ChildModel object.

Comment: Sure, change it to this: final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

Comment: But if I do this, how can I get the getters values of the object?

Comment: I think that you want to give the whole object to the adapter and not only one string. So you will have to change the _listDataChild to a type of HashMap<String, List<ChildModel>> and change your constructor so you can parse your whole ChildModel objects to the adapter by changing it the same way. Then you can leave the childText as a ChildModel type.